# Like count from "Like" button vs sharing URL on fanpage

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, xfbml

I'm not sure if I have an issue or just a misunderstanding.

I have the following link

http://theberrics.com/trickipedia/fakie-kickflip-hd.html

The "like" button on the page and graph api state I have 22 shares

https://graph.facebook.com/http://theberrics.com/trickipedia/fakie-kickflip-hd.html

However, on my Facebook fan page the same link has 70 plus likes

http://www.facebook.com/pages/The-Berrics/123390707714463

Up until a few days ago, I was under the impression that the likes that occurred on my fan page where eventually added to the count displayed on the "like" button for said link.

Am I wrong? Did something change? Help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://graph.facebook.com/http://theberrics.com/trickipedia/fakie-kickflip-hd.html shows the number of shares (people hitting share or liking it on the page its on as that shares it)

Liking its on your Fan Page is people liking that news entry not the link itself. If someone hits the share button on the same line as the like/comment/share then that will increase the share count.

Comment: Well that's the thing, they are "liking" the link on my fan page, http://www.facebook.com/pages/The-Berrics/123390707714463 it's the third post down as of right now. Only the "URL" was shared since a few days ago the likes occurring on link on my fan page are not be aggregated to the count on the like "button".

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem, up until recently likes and shares of URL on facebook.com were counted and combined in like/share count for that URL (i.e. number displayed on like button on that page). 
The count now only shows likes that were produced by like button, disregarding likes/shares of the same URL on facebook.com..

Did Facebook change that behaviour premamanently ? (it happened temporary before, but havent lasted so long, more than a month for now..)

Comment: I'm still having the same effect on all of my links posted on my fan page and the button on my website. I've reached out to FB on the official dev.group however I'm not getting any feedback.